# Track MongoDB performance?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to track 'query' performance in MongoDB? Specially testing indexes or subdocuments?

In sql you can run queries, see execution time and other analytic metrics.

I have a huge mongoDB collection and want to try different variations and indexes, not sure how to test it, would be nice to see how long did it take to find a record.. (I am new in MongoDB). Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two things here that you'll likely be familiar with.

1. Explain plans
2. Slow Logs

**Explain Plans**

[Here are some basic docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/optimization/) on explain. Running explain is as simple as `db.foo.find(query).explain()`. (*note that this actually runs the query, so if your query is slow this will be too*)

To understand the output, you'll want to check some of the docs on the slow logs below. You're basically given details about "how much index was scanned", "how many are found", etc. As is the case with such performance details, interpretation is really up to you. Read the docs above and below to point you in the right direction.

**Slow Logs**

By default, slow logs are active with a threshold of 100ms. [Here's a link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) to the full documentation on profiling. A couple of key points to get you started:

Get/Set profiling:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2); // 0 => none, 1 => slow, 2 => all
db.getProfilingLevel();
```

See slow queries:

```
db.system.profile.find()
```

Comment: Just to add after a few years: now the "new" recommended way of using explain is:  db.foo.explain().find(query).  Notice "explain" before "find". Also, specify explain(true) to get more details, such as the number of documents examined: db.foo.explain(true).find(query);  Type db.foo.explain().help to list the queries on which you may use explain.

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB has a query profiler you can turn on.
See: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler

Comment: see this page, in particular the See Also section. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler

Answer (score 0):

I recommend, based on my experience , to read mongologs with the mtools support ( https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools ), there are lots of feature which help reading output .

For instance I found very useful the `mlogFilter` command e.g.:

```
mlogfilter.exe   [PATH_TO_FILE_LOG]  --slow --json | mongoimport --db logsTest -c logCollection --drop
```

Launching this command you will record all the slow queries in a table.

Activating mongoprofiler could be a problem for performance in production environment, so you can achieve the same results reading logs.

Consider also that the `system.profile` collection is capped , so you should check the size of the capped collection because otherwise you could not find the queries you're looking for.