# How can i get the insert execution time in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I created a small java project in which I am trying to get back the execution time from the insert operation. So far I am just inserting data into the database without getting the execution time. Here is a code snippet:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost:27017" , options);
MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("personsDB");
MongoCollection<Person> collection = database.getCollection("personColl", Person.class);

Person person = new Person("Name");
collection.insertOne(person);
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400104/track-mongodb-performance should answer your question.

Comment: i set the profilinglevel to 2 in the mongodb console but it still didn't show the log in the console after i ran the project again

Comment: What do you get by executing `db.getProfilingStatus()`

Comment: By running that command i get the value 2.

Comment: you should get more than just a value, please post the whole output

Comment: This is the output: { "was" : 2, "slowms" : 100 }

Comment: You wrote, that you checked the console but the logged data is in the system.profile collection. Have you checked the collection?

Comment: No i have not. I did `db.system.profile.find().pretty()` and it displayed the info. But the ms showed 0. Is that the time it took inserting it or the time it took to find it when i used the find() ?

Comment: depends on what argument you gave `find()` for example 


`db.system.profile.find( { millis : { $gt : 5 } } ).pretty()` returns operations which are slower than 5ms

Comment: Oh, that's really nice! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB got a profiler which records data in the `system.profile` collection. 
There are different `profiling levels`:

`0` - the profiler is off

`1` - profling data for slow operations only (by default slower than 100ms)

`2` - collects profiling data for all database operations.

To set the profiling on you should use `db.setProfilingLevel(profiling-level)` 
where `profiling-level` is one of the above described values.

The interpretation of the data is explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-profiler/)